# How to make website look same on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

I am designing my site on a mac.  I used basic formatting and then when i want on to my pc, the wrapper width was too wide.  My question is what can i do so that my website looks the same on all browsers/os?

Comment: Considering adding the tag 'humour'.

Comment: Spend ten years in a small dark room, crying and swearing blind that you will murder anyone who ever worked on Internet Explorer. Along the way, you pick a few things up...

Comment: Shouldn't this question be in the SO FAQ?

Comment: bit of a general question there. Could you show us the code for your site that’s different between Mac and PC? Which browsers on Mac and PC are you testing in?

Comment: Maybe This Question is Too Old, but welcome to 2019: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Take http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ to heart. Looking good is a sensible goal, looking the same isn't.
2. Understand the standards (e.g. we can't tell if the difference is because of a bug or because you've provided instructions that only make sense for a particular window size)
3. Use them (don't forget to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) the HTML and CSS and to [lint](http://jslint.com) the JS)
4. Ensure you engage [standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes)
5. Learn about bugs in browsers

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a lot of testing in different broswers, in some cases you need to have different styles to make them cross browser compatiable, broswers render pages differently here is a nice tutorial with some tools to help you.

You should try and stick to the web standards as much as possible.

http://www.cookielabs.com/web-development/tools-to-keep-your-site-cross-browser-compatible/comment-page-1

Answer (score 1):

Use a css reset like Eric Meyer, CSSesta, BoilerPlate or YUI.

Sign up for https://browserlab.adobe.com/
 You can test the most commonly used browsers win & mac

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a couple of further points to @David Dorward's answer:

1. Validate your [(x)html](http://validator.w3.org/) and [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), and
2. Use a [css reset stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) to reduce the impact of differing browser-defaults for padding, font-weight, size, margin, etc... (the reset itself isn't, strictly, *necessary*, but understanding **how**, and **why**, it can help is a useful process in itself).

Answer (score 0):

> Autoprefixer uses data on the popularity of browsers and support for vendor prefixes by browsers. Based on this information, it arranges and deletes the prefixes. It can help you to get prefixes for: animations, transition, transform, grid, flex, flexbox and others. It is recommended by Google and used by Twitter and Alibaba.<sup>[source](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)</sup>

- [autoprefixer tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autoprefixer/info)
- [autoprefixer GitHub](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) – [PostCSS plugin](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) to parse CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/)
- [Autoprefixer CSS online](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) – web repl for the original autorefixer.