# How do I get this text highlighting not look the same across browsers?

Tags: css

I created this text highlighting, but in Chrome it has sharp edges and in Firefox round edges.

I would like it to look uniform across browsers.

How do I make it look the same in all browsers?

```css
a {  


  text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4vw !important;
   
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
    color: #0a0e0f !important;
    text-align: center !important;
   
    background: lightgrey !important;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.9vw transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text !important;
    padding-right:2vw;
  padding-left:2vw;
    
    font-style: italic !important;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  
   
}

div {
  
display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
 



  
}

body {
  
  background: grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div><a href="https://utopistlist.com/edible-wild-plants/">Less Known But Common Edible Wild Plants</a></div>
```

Comment: Different browsers use different browser engines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make website look same on all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987363/how-to-make-website-look-same-on-all-browsers)

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke) -webkit-text-stroke:

> Does not yet appear in any W3C specification. Was briefly included in a spec as the "text-outline" property, but this was removed.

and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke):

> Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

So, it is not a standard so browsers interpret as they will. And it does sound unwise to use it on any site that is expected to last.

Also, though I don't think this is affecting your look, the -webkit- prefix with background-clip is only interpreted by some browsers.

So, sadly, to get a consistent look you maybe are going to have to fall back on doing your own clip path (pretty nasty) or use an image.